# Renaming files by checking for strings within the filename that will be replaced with a corresponding new string

Tags: python, excel, batch-file, file-rename

I'm looking to rename a lot of files by replacing all instances of certain strings with a specific new string, but there is a large list of old-to-new pairs.  Let me provide examples to help explain...

```
**Original List**
abc_mno_pqr.txt
def_mno_lmn.txt
xyz_mno_efg.txt
xyz_tuv_pqr.txt
xyz_stu_bcd.txt
fgh_efg_klm.txt

Replace instances of:    with:
                  mno      345
                  xyz      123
                  efg      567

**Resulting List**
abc_345_pqr.txt
def_345_lmn.txt
123_345_567.txt
123_tuv_pqr.txt
123_stu_bcd.txt
fgh_567_klm.txt
```

[Here's the same text but with colorful highlighting to help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnGzz.png)

I don't have a preference as to a .bat file or python or even excel. Whatever tool you can think of to make it happen, I'll give it a shot!

### UPDATE: WHAT I DID WITH THE PROVIDED SOLUTION

I ended up writing it in javascript because I'm much more familiar with that than python.  What I have is not an all-in-one solution, but it took care of the heavy lifting.  Thanks to ettanany, whose solution was helpful in putting together the steps/logic to make this work.  The actual filenames I'm working with are not nearly as consistent in their naming structure as what I listed, but ettanany's answer certainly works for what I provided.

```
var mapping = {'mno': '345','xyz': '123','efg': '567'},result=[],newName=[],
    files = ['abc_mno_pqr.txt', 'def_mno_lmn.txt', 'xyz_mno_efg.txt', 
             'xyz_tuv_pqr.txt', 'xyz_stu_bcd.txt', 'fgh_efg_klm.txt'];

for (var item = 0; item < files.length; item++) { // loop thru files
    var thisFile = files[item].split('_');        // split file into segments
    newName = [];                                 // clear out newName array
    for (var i = 0; i < thisFile.length; i++) {   // loop thru segments
        for (var key in mapping) {                // loop thru mapping object
            if (key == thisFile[i]) {             // if key and segment match
                var segment = mapping[key];
                break;
            } else {
                var segment = thisFile[i];
            }
        }
        newName.push(segment);                    // add segment to array 
    }
    result.push(newName.join("_"));               // add new filename to results
    /* With how my files actually are named, 
    I knew I did not need to worry about 
    removing/appending the file extension. */
}
```

Comment: ```trans = str.maketrans('mnoxyzefg', '345123567'); [s.translate(trans) for s in orig_list]```

Comment: I feel like this could become an interesting code golf puzzle...

Comment: I think it is appropriate for SuperUser

Comment: @DrinkingBird, please edit your question and make it clear about the specific language that you want to use.

Comment: This is not a question but a task request, which is clearly off-topic here, unless you share your own efforts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Python, you can store old and new values in a dictionary and use them while using list comprehension with `split()` function for each item of your files list like below:

```
d = {'mno': '345', 'xyz': '123', 'efg': '567'}
files = ['abc_mno_pqr.txt', 'def_mno_lmn.txt', 'xyz_mno_efg.txt', 'fgh_efg_klm.txt']

res = ['_'.join([item.split('_')[0], d[item.split('_')[1]], item.split('_')[2]]) for item in files]

print(res)
# Output: ['abc_345_pqr.txt', 'def_345_lmn.txt', 'xyz_345_efg.txt', 'fgh_567_klm.txt']
```

**Edit:**

I noticed that also the first and the last part of your file name may need to be changed (not only the second part), a more generic solution is as follows:

```
res = []
for item in files:
    new_item = []
    for i in item[:-4].split('_'):
        if i in d:
            new_item.append(d[i])
        else:
            new_item.append(i)
    res.append('_'.join(new_item) + '.txt')
```

**Example of output:**

```
>>> d = {'mno': '345', 'xyz': '123', 'efg': '567'}
>>> files = ['def_mno_lmn.txt', 'xyz_mno_efg.txt', 'xyz_tuv_pqr.txt']
>>>
>>> res = []
>>> for item in files:
...     new_item = []
...     for i in item[:-4].split('_'):
...         if i in d:
...             new_item.append(d[i])
...         else:
...             new_item.append(i)
...     res.append('_'.join(new_item) + '.txt')
...
>>>
>>> files
['def_mno_lmn.txt', 'xyz_mno_efg.txt', 'xyz_tuv_pqr.txt']
>>> res
['def_345_lmn.txt', '123_345_567.txt', '123_tuv_pqr.txt']
```

Comment: You should state what language you are using - the OP was not specific as to the target language

Comment: @dbenham I added that in the beginning of my answer, thanks!